# Are there experimental arguments against elementary particles to have wobbling magnetic moment

Tags: quantum-spin, elementary-particles, magnetic-moment

Elementary particles having angular momentum and magnetic moment are observed or assummed as these are either always parallel or antiparallel. This condition could be satisfied even the instantaneous magnetic dipole moment of the particle have an angle with spin z-axis component and this circulate around the z-axis very fast, beyond range of instruments, maybe in a specific frequency like Zitterbewegung. This would look like to a magnetic top with magnetic dipole having an angle. Despite this, a compass needle would be aligned the spin axis because too slow to oscillate. Such a oscillating dipole would radiate classically but things works differently in quantum scale. So what are experimental arguments against this possibility?